# transform-origin equivalence using cssSandpaper

Tags: jquery, css-transforms

It's possible to do something like the following code with cssSandpaper?

```
-webkit-transform-origin:top left;
-moz-transform-origin:top left;
-o-transform-origin:top left;
-ms-transform-origin:top left;
transform-origin:top left;
```

This doen't works:

```
-sandpaper-transform-origin:top left;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, this is not currently a feature but is on the development roadmap. Check out [this article on their site](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/05/06/csssandpaper-now-supports-transform-translate-and-rgba-gradients/):

> *There is quite a bit more I would like to see cssSandpaper support*,
>   including: [...] **transform-origin**: modify the origin for transformations
>   of an element (this would allow, for example, developers to produce an
>   animation of planets rotating around the sun, which would be the
>   transform-origin point for all the planets).

Furthermore on a more recent article the developer stated in a comment:

> Until I implement the transform-origin CSS3 property, you may have to
>   use translations to simulate this.

Check out his comment on [this official docs page](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/).